# Is the achievement system dependant on which delivery mechanism you choose?

Tags: diablo-iii

When considering which version to purchase, physical or digital, I've noticed that some companies will have the achievement system directly tied to which edition you have purchased (for example, Steam).

Is the Diablo 3 achievement system in any way tied to the edition I purchase or is it all through Battle.Net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Battle.net is the server-side framework, not the local platform (such as Steam or Playstation). All Diablo editions behave the same in their interaction with Battle.net, achievements included.

Comment: What happen in buying CE for Diablo 3, is that you gain some FoS. Besides that @Oak answer is perfect

Comment: @MichelAyres indeed, but according to Bliz a FoS is not an achievement and gives no achievement points

Comment: indeed (why in my head I always say this in Britisher accent?), but I didn't said that it was an achievement, but I understand why you pointed out. So let me add this: FoS aren't achievements, but they stay in the same place, but in a different tab

Comment: @Oak WTF is a FOS? :)

Comment: @Stephen a Feat of Strength (FoS) is a Blizzard concept very similar to achievement, except that you can't really get them by doing anything in-game, it's more for things like [participating in the beta](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3980868668).